# Hide value on Jersey GET method

Tags: get, jersey, java-ee-6

Using Jersey's GET, is it possible to return an entity with only some fields? so others will not be displayed to the user? E.g. if I have an entity with personal information, can I return only the information which is not private as passwords?

Answer (score 0):

You should hide this field manually in control layer. Or you can code some DTOs, This is better to .

Comment: Is there any other way that use Jersey? I am working receiving and returning JSONs so I have used Jackson's @JsonIgnore notation and it does not work, I am using Maven, Java 1.7.0_09 and Jackson 1.9.8.

Comment: I'm using Spring MVC in current project, and I test it @JsonIgnore annotation works well. May be is there other config have error?